# Xcode Array to NSTableView

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstableview

I have done some searching, and some coding, some more searching, and then some more coding. I just can't get this to work on my own yet. I would like to get data from an array I have defined:

```
var allPublishers = [[String: String]]()
```

I will be filling up the array in chunks from an external API call. I can call a refresh every 100 chunks. Here is the population:

```
for i in 0 ..< json["publishers"].count {
    let pname: String = String(describing: json["publishers"][i]["publisher"]["account_name"])
    let pid: String = String(describing: json["publishers"][i]["publisher"]["publisher_id"])
    self.allPublishers.append(["name": pname, "id": pid])
}
```

For example, after the first 100 I call this function:

```
self.showPublishers()
```

Which for now just shows the type, for these purposes:

```
func showPublishers(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Type is: `Array<Dictionary<String, String>>`

A sample of a partially populated chunk is:

```
[["id": "1100l6141", "name": "014loyalia"], ["id": "1101l11949", "name": "030magazin"]]
```

I have an outlet to my NSTableView set up:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
```

Which is in my `Main.storyboard`:

[image: NSTableView]

I have no bindings on this as of yet, aside from the `ViewController.swift` outlet.

When I execute the program, the TableView updates the rows, but not with the values from the array:

[image: Rows]

Here are my `tableView` functions:

```
extension ViewController:NSTableViewDataSource{
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return allPublishers.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        return allPublishers[row][(tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue)!]
    }
}
```

Can anyone advise on how to populate this `NSTableView` with the actual data from `allPublishers` please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you also do some reading? Like [Table View Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html), chapter [Populating a Table View Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH14-SW1)?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @Willeke, words can't describe how helpful your comment was. I also did some reading on [Cocoa Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH13-SW1). The problem is that I can't get it to work - not that I haven't done research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are strongly discouraged from using a cell based table view.**

Cocoa Bindings and a view based table view are very easy to implement.

- Declare `allPublishers` as `dynamic`

  ```
  @objc dynamic var allPublishers = [[String: String]]() // however a custom class is highly recommended.
  ```
- In Interface Builder

  - Disconnect `datasource`
  - Change the table view from `Cell Based` to `View Based`
  - Bind the `Content` of the table view to `ViewController > allPublishers`
  - Bind the `Value` of the `Table View Cell` of the first column to `Table Cell View > objectValue.name`
  - Bind the `Value` of the `Table View Cell` of the second column to `Table Cell View > objectValue.id`

Please note the subtle but important difference *Table View Cell* and *Table Cell View*

**No further code required.**

Comment: Thanks for the input and direction. I am going to try and rebuild to manage this. Will leave this open for now.

Comment: This was the way to go, thanks for the direction. I have modified the way I built the APP to use a defined class, bound to array controller. This allowed me to remove the tableView code and also easily integrate an ArrayController search. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing a few things. First, I changed the "Content Mode" of the `Table View` in the `Main.storyboard` from "View Based" to "Cell Based":

[image: Content Mode]

This removed the requirements to map the cells to the parameter in the UI. Then, I changed the `ViewController.swift` function that called the columns:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[0] {
        return allPublishers[row]["name"]!
    } else if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[1] {
        return allPublishers[row]["id"]!
    }

    return nil
}
```

This now works like a charm.